# Create a composite primary key for a joiner table in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework-6

I have added the following business class to my Code First model.

```
public class NoteTag{ 

    [Key]
    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
    [Key]
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
}


public class Note {

protected Note() 
   {
     Tags = new List<NoteTag>()     
   }
   [Key]
   public int Id { get; set; }
   public virtual  List<NoteTag> Tags { get; set; }
}


public class Tag {

 protected Tag()
    {
      Notes= new List<NoteTag>()        
    }
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual  List<NoteTag> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

When I try to create a migration for it I get an error

```
EntityType 'NoteTag' has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.
```

The Note and Tag classes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reverse engineered the code from my database structure and it looks like I should not declare the joiner class

using System;
    using System.Data.Entity;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
    using System.Linq;

```
public partial class Model2 : DbContext
{
    public Model2()
        : base("name=Model2")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Note> Notes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Note>()
            .HasMany(e => e.Tags)
            .WithMany(e => e.Notes)
            .Map(m => m.ToTable("NoteTags"));
    }
}
```